# Testar campo data em consulta Oracle

Tags: oracle

preciso tirar uma dúvida, estou a usar este to_date mostrado abaixo, por enquanto não temos validação e as vezes o usuário põe o caractere (…) ou outro caractere inválido no campo data, quebrando assim o to_date, por favor como eu posso só pegar a data e quando for caractere inválido ele deverá mostrar na linha um dado em branco ou um data fixa pré estipulada, como se fosse um if pois a linha com a data inválida terá que vir também.

`TO_DATE(PESQUISA_MEDALHA.PREVISAO_ENVIO, 'DD/MM/YY') = trunc(SYSDATE)`

Comment: não poderia tratar esse erro na aplicação para não deixar o usuário informar data inválida? acho melhor do que fazer tratamento nesta condição (acredito que vc esteja realizando um select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma expressão regular para validar se o texto digitado está de acordo com o que você espera.

A função `regexp_like` verifica se o valor informado bate com o padrão esperado.
Veja como fica:

```
WITH datas AS (
SELECT '13/10/2000' DATA FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT '01/01/2020' DATA FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT '13 10/2000' DATA FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT '13/13/2000' DATA FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT '13/13/2100' DATA FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT '13/13/1800' DATA FROM dual  UNION ALL
SELECT '32/11/1800' DATA FROM dual )

SELECT DATA,
       CASE 
         WHEN Regexp_like(DATA,'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)') THEN 
           to_date(DATA,'dd/mm/yy') 
          ELSE 
           NULL 
       END sua_data
  FROM datas
```

Veja este exemplo rodando [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9aaa/7).

Mas como comentado acima, o ideal seria gravar os dados corretamente no banco de dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela gentileza e atenção em responder meu nobre, vou testar e depois ponho como resolvido, tudo de bom em sua vida!!!

Comment: Bruno é possível me explicar como você fez este REGEXP_LIKE a validação dentro da função, sou novo com sql...

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE valida se o seu "valor" bate com padrão de identificação de caracteres. No caso o padrão, de forma bem simples é algo como NN/NN/NNNN (Onde N representa um número). Mais informações de uma olhada no link: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular.

Comment: Li e entendi obrigado por compartilhar, valeu mesmo!!!

Comment: pode me ajudar novamente com seu sábio conhecimento, eu preciso desta mesma expressão regular mas agora preciso dela vindo além das datas horas minutos e segundos porém não consegui resolver sozinho, infelizmente...